# How to push a new branch in git?

Tags: git, terminal

Checked out master branch, made changes. How now to create a new branch,  commit changes, and push it to the remote?

Comment: @JohnZwinck The link you posted is for creating a branch this question is for making a healthy brunch. Two VERY different things...

Comment: Not a duplicate, the target says nothing about pushing.

Answer (score 41, accepted):

Four steps to get your changes committed locally and get them pushed to your server:

**Create a local branch and commit to it**

```
git checkout -b your-shiny-branch
git add .
git commit -m "Your Message"
```

**Push your branch to your remote (server)**

```
git push -u origin your-shiny-branch
```

If you then need to do further commits, start from command #2 and omit the `-u` flag during the `git push` on step #4.